# Supporting KVO when using composition to extend NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, key-value-observing

I have an array of NSMutableDictionary objects which are displayed in a master–detail interface which has a few text fields and a bunch of check boxes. The controls are bound to the dictionary keys, accessed through an array controller's `selection`.

I'd like to add some logic which clears one check box when another is cleared, and restores the original value if it's rechecked in the same session. Since I need to associate storage with the dictionary, and need to add code too, I thought I'd use composition to extend NSMutableDictionary.

Here's what I've done:

1. I created a `LibraryEntry` subclass which contains an NSMutableDictionary.
2. I implemented `forwardInvocation:`, `respondsToSelector:`, `methodSignatureForSelector:`, and after some trial-and-error `valueForUndefinedKey:`.
3. I created my forwarder objects.
4. I left the bindings as they were.

It loads up the data just fine, but I'm guessing that KVO won't work correctly. I'm guessing the binder is calling `addObserver:` on the my object but I haven't implemented anything special to handle it.

I thought of simply overriding `addObserver:` and forwarding the message to the dictionary. But if I do that the `observeValueForKey:` notifications won't originate from my object (the original receiver of addObserver), but from the dictionary.

Before I tried to implement more transparent forwarding for these KVO calls, I thought ... this is getting messy. I keep reading "use composition, not subclassing" to get behavior like this. Is it just the wrong pattern for this situation? Why? Because of KVO?

It seems like I'd have cleaner results if I abandon composition and choose one of these alternatives:

1. Use decorators, with one instance observing each dictionary
2. Store the transient keys in the dictionary and have the controller remove them before saving
3. Dispense with the dictionary and declare properties instead

Here's my code, in case it's helpful (`values` is the dictionary):

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if ([values respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]])
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:values];
    else
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ( [super respondsToSelector:aSelector] )
        return YES;
    else
        return [values respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}

- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) signature = [values methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    return signature;
}

-(id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [values valueForKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a combination of Objective-C associated storage, and some blocks, you could hook up arbitrary behaviors to a dictionary (or any other KVO compliant object) and solve your problem that way.  I cooked up the following idea that implements a generic KVO-triggers-block mechanism and coded up and example that appears to do the sort of thing you want it to do, and does not involve subclassing or decorating foundation collections.

First the public interface of this mechanism:

```
typedef void (^KBBehavior)(id object, NSString* keyPath, id oldValue, id newValue, id userInfo);

@interface NSObject (KBKVOBehaviorObserver)

- (void)addBehavior: (KBBehavior)block forKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath options: (NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options userInfo: (id)userInfo;
- (void)removeBehaviorForKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath;

@end
```

This will allow you to attach block-based observations/behaviors to arbitrary objects.  The task you describe with the checkboxes might look something like this:

```
- (void)testBehaviors
{
    NSMutableDictionary* myModelDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    KBBehavior behaviorBlock = ^(id object, NSString* keyPath, id oldValue, id newValue, id userInfo) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* modelDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*)object;
        NSMutableDictionary* previousValues = (NSMutableDictionary*)userInfo;

        if (nil == newValue || (![newValue boolValue]))
        {
            // If the master is turning off, turn off the slave, but make a note of the previous value
            id previousValue = [modelDictionary objectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];

            if (previousValue)
                [previousValues setObject: previousValue forKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];
            else
                [previousValues removeObjectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];

            [modelDictionary setObject: newValue forKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];
        }
        else
        {
            // if the master is turning ON, restore the previous value of the slave
            id prevValue = [previousValues objectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];

            if (prevValue)
                [modelDictionary setObject:prevValue forKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];
            else
                [modelDictionary removeObjectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];
        }
    };

    // Set the state...
    [myModelDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"slaveCheckbox"];
    [myModelDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"masterCheckbox"];

    // Add behavior
    [myModelDictionary addBehavior: behaviorBlock forKeyPath: @"masterCheckbox" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew userInfo: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

    // turn off the master
    [myModelDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: @"masterCheckbox"];

    // we now expect the slave to be off...
    NSLog(@"slaveCheckbox value: %@", [myModelDictionary objectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"]);

    // turn the master back on...
    [myModelDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"masterCheckbox"];

    // now we expect the slave to be back on, since that was it's previous value
    NSLog(@"slaveCheckbox value: %@", [myModelDictionary objectForKey: @"slaveCheckbox"]);


}
```

I implemented the block/KVO hook-up by creating an object to keep track of the blocks and userInfos, then have that be the KVO observer.  Here's what I did:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void* kKVOBehaviorsKey = &kKVOBehaviorsKey;    

@interface KBKVOBehaviorObserver : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary* mBehaviorsByKey;
    NSMutableDictionary* mUserInfosByKey;
}
@end

@implementation KBKVOBehaviorObserver

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        mBehaviorsByKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        mUserInfosByKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mBehaviorsByKey release];
    mBehaviorsByKey = nil;

    [mUserInfosByKey release];
    mUserInfosByKey = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)addBehavior: (KBBehavior)block forKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath userInfo: (id)userInfo
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        id copiedBlock = [[block copy] autorelease];
        [mBehaviorsByKey setObject: copiedBlock forKey: keyPath];
        [mUserInfosByKey setObject: userInfo forKey: keyPath];
    }
}

- (void)removeBehaviorForKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [mUserInfosByKey removeObjectForKey: keyPath];
        [mBehaviorsByKey removeObjectForKey: keyPath];
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == kKVOBehaviorsKey)
    {
        KBBehavior behavior = nil;
        id userInfo = nil;

        @synchronized(self)
        {
            behavior = [[[mBehaviorsByKey objectForKey: keyPath] retain] autorelease];
            userInfo = [[[mUserInfosByKey objectForKey: keyPath] retain] autorelease];
        }

        if (behavior) 
        {
            id oldValue = [change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
            id newValue = [change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
            behavior(object, keyPath, oldValue, newValue, userInfo);
        }
    }
}

@end

@implementation NSObject (KBKVOBehaviorObserver)

- (void)addBehavior: (KBBehavior)block forKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath options: (NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options userInfo: (id)userInfo
{
    KBKVOBehaviorObserver* obs = nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        obs = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kKVOBehaviorsKey);
        if (nil == obs)
        {
            obs = [[[KBKVOBehaviorObserver alloc] init] autorelease];    
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kKVOBehaviorsKey, obs, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
    }

    // Put the behavior and userInfos into stuff...
    [obs addBehavior: block forKeyPath: keyPath userInfo: userInfo];

    // add the observation    
    [self addObserver: obs forKeyPath: keyPath options: options context: kKVOBehaviorsKey];
}

- (void)removeBehaviorForKeyPath: (NSString*)keyPath
{
    KBKVOBehaviorObserver* obs = nil;

    obs = [[objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kKVOBehaviorsKey) retain] autorelease];    

    // Remove the observation
    [self removeObserver: obs forKeyPath: keyPath context: kKVOBehaviorsKey];

    // remove the behavior
    [obs removeBehaviorForKeyPath: keyPath];
}

@end
```

One thing that's sort of unfortunate, is that you have to remove the observations/behaviors in order to break down the transitive retain cycle between the original dictionary and the observing object, so if you don't remove the behaviors, you'll leak the collection. But overall this pattern should be useful.

Hope this helps.

---

Comment: This is a thoughtful and elegant solution to the problem of adding behaviors requiring storage to foundation collections or other KVO-based objects that are difficult to subclass. I can imagine using it especially with NSArrays.

Comment: With dictionaries there's a flaw, because the associated storage 'is' the dictionary: `-setValue:forKey:` === `-setObject:forKey:`. To provide associative storage independent from the original dictionary you could add a third NSMutableDictionary ivar to `KBKVOBehaviorObserver`, instantiate it in `-init`, and pass a reference to each call of the behavior block.

Comment: In terms of memory management: since the behavior observes the dictionary, will the dictionary retain it, or do I need to retain the behaviors separately? Apart from that question, it sounds like the common problem of using KVO with collection elements: when they're deleted, the observer needs to be removed.

Comment: objc_setAssociatedObject is a completely separate mechanism from dictionaries. To prove this to yourself using this example, set a breakpoint on the call to objc_setAssociatedObject and check the count of the dictionary before and after the call. They'll be the same. There's no danger there -- it's totally separate. The neatest feature of objc_setAssociatedObject is that if you set an association with the copy/retain/retain_nonatomic policy, that retain will be *automatically released* when the object to which it was associated is dealloced.  This can be abused in all sorts of awesome ways.

Comment: The classic problem with KVO-observing collections is that, by itself, it's almost never what you actually want to do. Instead you want to KVO observe the things **in** the collection, along with just enough observation of the collection itself to catch insertions/removals/replacements. Unless you explicitly need something different, the easiest path there is to use NS[Object|Array|Tree]Controller, and let those classes do that heavy lifting for you.  See here for more info: http://bit.ly/rVWQSn

Comment: Huh. This was the test I ran. It printed out both keys.     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:@"real" forKey:@"therealkey"];
    [dict setValue:@"foobar" forKey:@"theassociativekey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);

Comment: Yeah, cause you added both of those things to the same collection explicitly.  Having the key say "associative" confers no special meaning.

Comment: After that code, NSLog(@"keys: %@", [dict allKeys]); prints keys: (
    theassociativekey,
    therealkey
)

Comment: I guess I'm missing it. I thought setValue:forKey: was the way to use associative storage.

Comment: Nope. setValue:forKey: on an NSMutableDictionary is the same thing as setObject:forKey: except that the key must be an NSString and if the value is nil, it's equivalent to removeObjectForKey:. objc_setAssociatedObject is totally separate, managed by the runtime, opaque to the consumer in terms of implementation, and lacks an ObjC message based interface.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5601/discussion-between-ipmcc-and-noa)